# Pandas Merge 2 dataframe if one of the values are same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

`df1`:

```
     id            color
0    005           green
1    005           blue
```

`df2`:

```
    user_id         name
0    005            eric
```

I'm trying to user `pd.dataframe.merge` to merge these 2 dataframes

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1, left_on='user_id', right_on='id')[['id', 'name', 'color']]
```

I got the following result:

`df2`:

```
      id       name     color
0    005       eric     green
1    005       eric     blue
```

---

Are there ways for me to combine these 2 columns into 1? for example:

`df2`:

```
      id       name     color
0    005       eric     green,blue
```

Comment: after you done merging use `out=df2.groupby(['id','name'],as_index=False)['color'].agg(','.join)`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df2.merge(df1.groupby("id")["color"].agg(','.join),
              left_on="user_id", right_on="id")

  user_id  name       color
0     005  eric  green,blue
```